# Задание роутов в популярных php-frameworks

Tags: php, laravel, php-frameworks

Подскажите, мне нужно вручную задать url-страницы. 
То есть к примеру в форме ввожу имя "aboutus", записывает в базы данных, и создается страница с таким url. 
Есть ли такие , в мини-фреймворках или в популярных фреймворках типо **laravel** (ибо им пользуюсь), дополнительные пакеты к примеру чтобы можно было установить (с помощью composer).
 Мне это нужна для маленького проекта, так что гигантские framework's лучше не советуете. И да, желательно с хорошей документацией (английской или русской) Благодарю за помощь. 
То не хочется писать свои костыльный фреймворк ради этого, хотелось бы что-то изучить и просто установить, в приоритете: Lumen.

Comment: А в чем собсна вопрос? У `Lumen` роуты есть и они работают как и в `Laravel`. или вы о чем?

Comment: В lumen, как и в Laravel, задаются вручную. Мне автоматически надо сделать, чтобы в форме указал "aboutus", и у меня автоматически этот роут сам создался. Вот как вот такое сделать можно, в этом вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так никакой проблемы же нет...
Ну к примеру laravel:

```
model - Page  
id, route, html
```

routes/web.php

```
 Route::get('/{route?}', function($route = null){
  $page = App\Page::where('route', $route)->firstOrFail();
  return view('page', compact('page'));
 });
```

resources/views/page.blade.php

```
{{$page->html}}
```

Ну и создавайте сколько хотите страниц...

Comment: Привет. Я не понял, как сделать первую часть.
Вот ты указал:  Route::get('/{route}', function($route){ ...
В route что должно вписываться, с ячейки "route" с базы данных?
Объясни пожалуйста подробнее, если можешь. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Смотри, ты делаешь указанную модель и к ней форму, там указываешь маршрут ну и собственно содержание страницы как в обычных cms, можно и расширить указать там алиас для менюшки, но не суть. Создал несколько страниц, напрмер about, contacts и т.д после этого они будут сразу доступны по адресам domain/pages/about domain/pages/contacts. Т.е по маршруту /domain/pages/ЧТОУГОДНО система будешь чекать базу на наличие записи с маршрутом "ЧТОУГОДНО" и возвращать 404 если не найдено!

Comment: Все сделал, благодарю. Только один вопрос, а как сделать без роута, то есть просто "/". То в базе указываю, и вот это не работает к сожалению

Comment: Поправил. Домашняя страница - первая с нулевым роутом

Comment: Знаю, что уже надоел наверное) 
Но не подскажешь, еще такой вопрос, не работает через "/", пример "test/test" , уже как  только не пробывал route исправить, что-то не катит

Comment: О...с подкаталогами сложнее... первое что в голову пришло, на фиксированное количество уровней Route::get('/{r1?}/{r2?}/{r3?}', function($r1 = null, $r2 = null, $r3 = null){ $route = preg_replace('{/$}', '', implode('/', [$r1, $r2, $r3])); });